# How to get the output of gcc or clang after applying the #pragma (OpenMP)?

Tags: gcc, clang, openmp

How can I get the output after applying the `#pragma omp` with gcc or clang?

Refer to this document [OpenMP Reference LLVM](http://openmp.llvm.org/Reference.pdf), page 12, section 1.7, where the example is shown. I want to get the transformed code.

I am looking for something similar to `gcc -E file.c > file.i`, but instead of generating the preprocessed code, I want the OpenMP transformations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `gcc -fopenmp -fdump-tree-ompexp file.c`

Comment: It is that the Intermediate Representation of the gcc, isn't it? Is this the nearest result I could get? I am looking for the same example as the page 12, section 1.7 (something near to the C code). Maybe in LLVM?

Comment: Yes, gcc applies all OpenMP transformations to its intermediate representation. It's not possible to restore C code from it. I'm not familiar with LLVM.